# How to prepare for/win the 100 man kumite?

Tags: karate, kumite

[In this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100-man_kumite) and in [the beginning of this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9e_iO0odR0) they reference a 100 man kumite, in which you have to fight over and over again against a new opponent that is of similar or higher skill for 100 rounds. What are the specific details of the matches and how would I prepare or train or strategize for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ExzDMT8DSCg), documenting Australian Judd Reid's successful completion of the 100 Man Kumite, should give you some indication of how difficult it is. In some ways it is the ultimate achievement and honour for a practitioner of Kyokushin Karate, and is widely respected by experienced fighters of many discplines who are familiar with it.

Reid, who is a lifelong practitioner of Kyokushin, is an immensely powerful, dedicated and gifted athlete. I mention this only to add weight to how close he came to failing.

If you've ever tried to hit and kick a heavy bag with intensity for 2 minutes, or better still, sparred or fought full contact without pads or gloves for one round or more, you can begin to *contemplate* what 100 rounds of similar exertion against elite black belts might require. Most of these fighters would likely deem it a severe insult to the candidate - and impolite of them - to fight him or her with less than maximum effort; to try to assist in any way.

To describe the training requirements for such a task here would require too much information. Suffice to say, it is likely a 30-year project. Preparation must address the mental resilience and determination as much as the physical. As the video shows, it is largely a mental endeavour once you have obtained sufficient skill. Accruing the necessary physical skills and endurance will be unachievable for many or most, which is partly why this is an invitation-only test.

Start training. If you enjoy it, keep training; consistently and with a concentrated emphasis on continual improvement. Make sure you have access to a number of excellent teachers and sparring partners. Learn about nutrition, flexibility, mobility and strength training. Start competing in full contact events as soon as your teacher deems you ready. Compete as often as you can whilst bearing in mind the need to avoid chronic injury. Don't compete if you're injured. Play the long game. Be patient. Build slowly but steadily. Rushing will lead to injury and possibly to burnout. Speak to 30, 50 and 100 kumite veterans. Let your ambition be known, and you will likely be told of the many precursor events, qualifications, tasks and assessments which you must complete first.

One of the most important factors for any participant in high-volume fighting assessments such as this is an ability to fight efficiently; ie. to conserve as much energy as possible. This requires an ability to relax (as much as possible) during combat, to master breath, and to employ a wide variety of simple, effective techniques which finish fights as quickly as possible.

Many of the better Kyokushin schools have live-in, high-frequency, rapid-progression 'ushi-deshi' programs. This would be a good way to test your dedication to the style. As far as I know, the Headquarters of the founding Kyokushin organisation remain in Tokyo, where it offers elite Ushi Deshi programs to students from around the world who show exceptional promise.

Good luck.

Comment: So basically, you are saying that there is no shortcut/strategy/training method and that it is extremely hard, near impossible, grueling, grinding, and rough, and that I just have to start training?

Comment: Yes. Spot on. It is likely a 30 year project. You have to dedicate a large proportion of your life to Kyokushin to have a chance of being close to good enough to be invited.

Comment: I also noticed from my own kyokushin class that real kyokushin is supposed to be tough and no nonsense.

Comment: Yes. But you must enjoy it. If you don't,  the training will likely prove unsustainable. Everyone has down phases; periods where they tire of the routine and exertion, but success of this sort demands a drive powerful enough to ensure you keep at it through the tough times; the plateaus, the injuries, the boredom, the humiliations, the failures.

Comment: So how do I do the grind/hard work?

Comment: The video shows him practicing the moves over and over again.

Comment: You apparently already train. You will either be driven enough to continue or you won't. It is difficult to manufacture motivation. IMHO the most important thing is to enjoy training. If you don't,  maybe persevere for a bit, but ultimately, what are you doing it for if not for enjoyment? Don't confuse the 100 Man with self defense, by the way. You can be an awesome Kyokushin fighter and not know how to deal with a decent boxer, for example.

Comment: So I just keep doing what I've been doing?

Comment: I don't know what you've been doing.

Comment: Kyokushin classes and gym workouts.

Comment: Yep. If you're having fun, keep it up! One belt at a time. Don't rush the strength training. Think turtle, not hare.